# Where memory gone (.NET application)

Tags: memory, windbg

I created a full dump of some process which (process or its dump file) takes ~7GB.
The process is WCF service. When starting it takes ~1.4GB and grows up after some time, but never takes more than 2-3GB. Never until today. Now it takes almost all free memory.

In WinDbg when running the !dumpheap -stat command I get next:

```
000007fef929ac78    15038      4878720 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
000007fe9c4d4d20   118818      7604352 BLL.EmailOptOutBLL
000007fef92a0ec0   727949     17470776 System.RuntimeMethodHandle
000007fef9287fe8    10794     17832144 System.Reflection.Emit.__FixupData[]
000007fe9c6dc5c0   907500     36300000 ExactTargetEmail.etAPI.APIProperty
000007fef927f1b8   409602     39034712 System.Object[]
000007fe9c6d9858   302500     41140000 ExactTargetEmail.etAPI.ObjectExtension
000007fef929f058    49141     52089645 System.Byte[]
000007fef929aee0  2487200    152416116 System.String
00000000013a6030      941   1601636252      Free
```

The total size of all listed objects are about 2.3GB

The !eeheap -gc command lists 4 heaps with total size 6.3GB

The question: where remaining  7GB - 2.3GB = 4.7GB? How can I find where (in WinDbg or other tool) are they?

---

!Address -summary

```
0:000> !address -summary


Failed to map Heaps (error 80004005)

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    387      7fb`98d72000 (   7.983 Tb)           99.79%
<unclassified>                         1141        4`53c8f000 (  17.309 Gb)  98.28%    0.21%
Image                                  2387        0`11ed5000 ( 286.832 Mb)   1.59%    0.00%
Stack                                   141        0`0168c000 (  22.547 Mb)   0.13%    0.00%
TEB                                      47        0`0005e000 ( 376.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
NlsTables                                 1        0`00023000 ( 140.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
ActivationContextData                     4        0`00007000 (  28.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
CsrSharedMemory                           1        0`00005000 (  20.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                             671        4`50a59000 (  17.260 Gb)  98.00%    0.21%
MEM_IMAGE                              3014        0`15304000 ( 339.016 Mb)   1.88%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               38        0`01521000 (  21.129 Mb)   0.12%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                387      7fb`98d72000 (   7.983 Tb)           99.79%
MEM_RESERVE                             799        2`af232000 (  10.737 Gb)  60.96%    0.13%
MEM_COMMIT                             2924        1`b804c000 (   6.875 Gb)  39.04%    0.08%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                          897        1`a2017000 (   6.531 Gb)  37.08%    0.08%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       333        0`103c9000 ( 259.785 Mb)   1.44%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                           899        0`03940000 (  57.250 Mb)   0.32%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                          527        0`01c95000 (  28.582 Mb)   0.16%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                  132        0`003b9000 (   3.723 Mb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                   88        0`00208000 (   2.031 Mb)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                47        0`000d2000 ( 840.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              1        0`00004000 (  16.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      5`3fa00000      7f9`5b0e0000 (   7.974 Tb)
<unclassified>                            1`0a3ef000        0`f5611000 (   3.834 Gb)
Image                                   7fe`e7e9a000        0`01338000 (  19.219 Mb)
Stack                                     0`007c0000        0`0007b000 ( 492.000 kb)
TEB                                     7ff`ffe9a000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
NlsTables                               7ff`fffb0000        0`00023000 ( 140.000 kb)
ActivationContextData                     0`00030000        0`00004000 (  16.000 kb)
CsrSharedMemory                           0`7efe0000        0`00005000 (  20.000 kb)
PEB                                     7ff`fffdf000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

---

!eeheap -gc

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 4
------------------------------
Heap 0 (00000000013d4ad0)
generation 0 starts at 0x00000001066b2868
generation 1 starts at 0x00000001066984b8
generation 2 starts at 0x00000000ffa01000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000000ffa00000  00000000ffa01000  00000001067ea940  0x6de9940(115251520)
Large object heap starts at 0x00000004ffa01000
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000004ffa00000  00000004ffa01000  0000000509173080  0x9772080(158802048)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x1055b9c0 (274053568) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 1 (00000000013d9960)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000000203ef0168
generation 1 starts at 0x0000000203d01f78
generation 2 starts at 0x00000001ffa01000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000001ffa00000  00000001ffa01000  000000027c2af408  0x7c8ae408(2089477128)
Large object heap starts at 0x000000050fa01000
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000050fa00000  000000050fa01000  000000050fa01018  0x18(24)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x7c8ae420 (2089477152) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 2 (0000000001e48f90)
generation 0 starts at 0x000000030552c398
generation 1 starts at 0x00000003054a0920
generation 2 starts at 0x00000002ffa01000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000002ffa00000  00000002ffa01000  0000000374600330  0x74bff330(1958736688)
Large object heap starts at 0x000000051fa01000
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000051fa00000  000000051fa01000  000000051fd87130  0x386130(3694896)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x74f85460 (1962431584) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 3 (0000000001e4bfa0)
generation 0 starts at 0x00000004059eaa60
generation 1 starts at 0x00000004057d3308
generation 2 starts at 0x00000003ffa01000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000003ffa00000  00000003ffa01000  0000000471912bb8  0x71f11bb8(1911626680)
Large object heap starts at 0x000000052fa01000
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000052fa00000  000000052fa01000  0000000534f2d468  0x552c468(89310312)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x7743e020 (2000936992) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x1791cd260 (6326899296) bytes.
```

Comment: !address -summary   Will give you an overview of the process. Show us the output

Comment: @Kjell Gunnar: here. And if we are talking about this command - what the 7.9Tb means? It's not terabytes, right? The machine doesn't have all these memory or even disk

Comment: this is the free virtual memory of the process. 64Bit programs can have 8TB virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the 7.983 Tb is just free virtual space 
I.E space NOT (yet) used.

Your !address –summary shows 17 GB , and the error
 “Failed to map Heaps” means that native heaps are included in < unclassified >

To my knowledge your 17 GB contains

```
a) Native heaps,
b) .NET heaps
c) Areas allocated by VirtualAlloc
d) Memory mapped files
```

The .NET heap contributes with 6 GB, leaving 11 GB to investigate.
For checking the native heaps, you can try with:

```
!heap –s
```

but the sizes may not be reliable if they are big, and it may not work since the !address –summary was not able to classify.
You can also try a:

```
!address
     BaseAddress      EndAddress+1        RegionSize     Type       State                 Protect             Usage
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+        0`00000000        0`00010000        0`00010000             MEM_FREE    PAGE_NOACCESS                         Free       
+        0`00010000        0`00020000        0`00010000 MEM_MAPPED  MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     Heap       [ID: 1; Handle: 0000000000010000; Type: Segment]
+        0`00020000        0`00021000        0`00001000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT  PAGE_READWRITE                     <unknown>
```

Be prepared for a long output (so redirect to a file), here you can see
all your memory regions and the file names for mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting your dump file to be closer to 17 GB (as Kjell points out) than 7 GB. I don't think you really want to use 7 GB in your question but I could be wrong. Check out [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks/) to learn more about the total size show in !dumpheap -summary.

What is relevant is that the GC heaps are using 6.2 GB which makes up the lion share of the committed memory (6.875 GB). This is what you most likely care about. Your app uses 4 GC heaps and of them, Heap 0 is a bit smaller (~274 MB) than the other 3, which use close to 2 GB. If your app isn't having memory pressure then it might not be efficient to spend time garbage collecting.

Showing your !address and !heap -s output might help understand why there is 10.737 Gb memory reserved.